# Оформление предложения с вопросом внутри

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, прямая-речь, сложное-предложение, несобственно-прямая-речь

> Поэтому на вопрос "рождается ли человек гением", я отвечу негативно.

Как вообще расставляются знаки препинания в такого типа предложениях?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Самое простое — включить задаваемый вопрос в состав предложения (в качестве косвенной речи). Тогда пунктуационно слова вопроса оформляются как придаточное предложение (т. к. в нем есть своя грамматическая основа), разрывающее главное, — то есть обрамляются запятыми.

*Поэтому на вопрос, **рождается ли человек гением,** я отвечу негативно.*

Вот похожее предложения из Нацкорпуса:
Поэтому на вопрос, **грозит ли нам дефолт,** ответ следующий. [Сергей Гук. Лежачий камень реформы // «Время МН», 2003.01.27]

2. Если уж очень хочется (или вдруг — очень нужно) выделить сам вопрос как цитату, тогда пишем предложение по правилам оформления прямой речи: двоеточие, кавычки, заглавная буква, знак вопроса, кавычки, тире (**А: "П?" – а.**).
   Но мне кажется, что это громоздко.

*Поэтому на вопрос: **«Рождается ли человек гением?»** — я отвечу негативно.*

[Чужая речь и способы ее передачи](http://gramota.ru/class/coach/punct/45_192)